# Javascript - Get position of the element of the array

Tags: javascript

For instance, a variable named arrayElements of array type contains [1,2,3,4].

How do i get the position of which that has the value "3" in the array variable besides using loop?

thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

consider using `indexOf`, it returns the 0-based position of the element in the array.

e.g.

```
[1,2,3,4].indexOf(3); // produces 2
```

Note that this method is not available in IE 8 and below.

Comment: If the array was [1, 2, 3, 4, 3], how would you get the position of both 3s on two different variables?

Comment: For reference, you can use the Array.reduce Method to return an array containing the position of multiple elements. The following code returns an position array [2,4] - the position of both 3s.  var array =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 3].reduce(function(array, n, i) { if (n===3) array.push(i); return array; },[] );

Answer (score 4):

Or simple use a for loop:

```
function getPosition(elementToFind, arrayElements) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i += 1) {
        if (arrayElements[i] === elementToFind) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null; //not found
}

getPosition(3, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery provides yout with an "inArray" functionality, similar to PHP:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
console.log( jQuery.inArray(3, a) ); //returns 2
```

If you're already using jQuery in your project, this would be the way to go!
jQuery uses indexOf (the fastest solution) if possible and steps back to a loop based solution if not.

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out by some answers, arrays in newer browsers have methods like `indexOf` `map` and `forEach` that are *very* convenient for avoiding writing lots of for-loops.

If you need to support old environments without these functions I would *strongly recommend* using a library (or writing one of your own) to implement those very common array operations (kind of how soc suggested).

```
var arrayfn = (function(){
    var M = {};

    M.indexOf = function(array, item){ ... };

    M.contains = function(array, item){ return M.indefOf(array, item) !== -1; };

    M.map = function(array, callback){ ... };
}());

arrayfn.contains([1,2,3], 2);
```

Most popular JS frameworks should already have most of these builtin anyway. Out of the top of my head I remember Dojo, jQuery and Underscore have some of these functions, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This example only demonstrate that is possible the use of `map()` to return each element of the array. Once we have it, we retrieve the element's index in the array:

```
function searchPosition(elementToFind, array) {
    return array.map(function(el) {
        return el;
    }).indexOf(elementToFind);
}

searchPosition(3, [1, 2, 3, 4]); // returns 2
```

**BONUS:**

This is not a part of the OP's question, but if you want to retrieve the position of the first element in the array that satisfies certain condition, you can do it with the [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) function provided in the ES6:

```
var array = [101, 90, 104, 80];

function findFirstLessNumber(element) {
  return element < 100;
}

console.log(array.findIndex(findFirstLessNumber)); // returns 1 (the position of 90)
```

Comment: @jhpratt I have already made it, and added more code to explain some other things !