# Get indices (indexes) of all occurrences of an element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array. For example, [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]. How do I get the position of the first "3" and the second "3" without altering the array? I realize that this is a similar question:
[Javascript - Get position of the element of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863549/javascript-get-position-of-the-element-of-the-array), but I want to find the position of both "3"s. Does anyone know how to do this? (without jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **JUST** have two elements you want to know the position for, you can use

`indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a general function that returns the positions of **all** the occurrences of an element you specify in an array:

### Code:

```
Array.prototype.indicesOf = function(query) {
    var indices = [];
    var x = this.indexOf(query);
    while(x != -1) {
        indices.push(x);
        x = this.indexOf(query, x + 1);
    }
    return indices;
};
```

### Usage:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var positions = myArray.indicesOf(3); // `positions` is now [2, 6]
```

#### Another example:

```
var thingsTheySaid = ["Hello", "Hi", "Greetings", "Howdy",
                      "Good morning", "Hello"];

console.log(thingsTheySaid.indicesOf("Hello")); // Logs [0, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, you can use this:

```
a = arr.indexOf(3);
b = arr.indexOf(3,a+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 var a = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4];
 var pos = [];
 for(var i=0;i<a.length;i ++){
   if(a[i] === 3){
    pos.push(i);
   }else{

   }
}
alert(pos[0]);
alert(pos[1]);
</script>
```

You could loop through the array and 
push all the indices onto another array whenever
it equals the number you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could:

```
var matchingIndexes = [];
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4];
x.forEach(function (element, index) { 
    if (element === 3) { 
        matchingIndexes.push(index); 
    }
});
```

As for output:

```
console.log(matchingIndexes)
```

*[2, 6]*

You could certainly wrap this as a function or use the array.prototype like already mentioned.