# How to delete array item from LocalStorage and Update UI in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array in my localStorage, what I want to do is give the user the ability to remove items from this array. I have made changes to the UI based on `event.target.parentNode`. But I want to remove the individual items based on their index from localStorage. Do I need to use `indexOf`or `forEach`. My current code does not work, I don't think I have to split the array, so I can access individual items as it is already an array? the function is below - any idea's?

```
function removeItemsLocalStorage() {
    const listUl = domElements.app.querySelector('.saveUl');
    listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {

          // below tis to remove the element from the DOM, works ok.
          let li = event.target.parentNode;
          let ul = li.parentNode;
          ul.removeChild(li);

          //The code below seems abit iffy to me? as its here I am trying to remove from the index of the array
          let displayItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Shopping List"));
          let ele = displayItems.split(",");
          var index = ele.indexOf(1);
          ele.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

localstorage array is like:

```
["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
```

**Saving to localStorage**

```
function saveItems(ele) {
    localStorage.setItem('Shopping List', JSON.stringify(ele));
    let displayItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Shopping List"));
    domElements.saveList.innerHTML = displayArray(displayItems);
}

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        saveItems(data);
    });
```

Error when clicking on the `removeItemsLocalStorage()` function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: displayItems.split is not a function
```

Comment: How are you adding items to "Shopping List"?

Comment: An click event which saves the items`function saveItems(ele) {
    localStorage.setItem('Shopping List', JSON.stringify(ele));
    let displayItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Shopping List"));
    domElements.saveList.innerHTML = displayArray(displayItems);
}`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code.

Comment: Updated the question, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array item from localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage)

Comment: No the thing I am confused if how to get the index value of the array in localStorage

Comment: There are no arrays in localStorage; only strings. That's why you have things like `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. It's not clear what `ele` is in your `saveItems` function. If it's an array of strings, you're set; once you remove the item, just pass the array (sans item) to `saveItems`. To get the index, use the answers to [Javascript - Get position of the element of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8863549/215552)

Comment: I can see in that question how to get the position based on passing a parameter into the method. But how would I get that based on the user clicking on each element i.e. like a ToDo app? either i'm getting confused for no reason or just not getting it. I have edited my code to the point now, the array is deleting from the end not on each item.

Comment: Well, there's not much to go on in the question. Basically, you need to figure out a way of linking the button clicked to the element in the array. I can't tell you how to do that from what is given in the question.

Comment: I think this will lead to another question as my code has adjusted to give a new behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply delete stuff from local storage by doing:

```
  localStorage.removeItem('Shopping List');
```

So what you should do is getting the name of the item you want to delete and pass it to the removeItem function from localStorage. You should not have to loop over the localStorage to remove it by index.

Since in your case the "Shopping List" is an object, the common approach to solve this is by doing splicing it by the index and setting the item again.

```
list.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem('Shopping List', JSON.stringify(list));
```

Comment: That deletes the entire array from localStorage, what I want is to click on individual items and delete them?

Comment: Updated my answer for you @Sole

Answer (score 2):

```
let displayItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Shopping List"));
```

Here you are fetching the "Shopping List" item from your local storage, and storing its content inside your `displayItems` variable.

```
let ele = displayItems.split(",");
var index = ele.indexOf(1);
ele.splice(index, 1);
```

Now your local variable `ele` contains your updated array. But in your localStorage, nothing has changed, and the "Shopping List" is still the same. You need to update that value, for example by doing :

```
var newShoppingList = ele.join(',');
localStorage.setItem('shoppingList', newShoppingList);
```

Comment: Why would I need to split the Array if it is already like `["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]`

Comment: Also the above is giving `Uncaught TypeError: displayItems.split is not a function
`

Comment: The first and second chunk of code here are copied from your original post, only the third one is a proposition

Comment: You need to serialize the array before storing it  `localStorage.setItem('shoppingList', JSON.stringify(newShoppingList);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the value ',' seperated but as a string in local storage, then you have to use `split` function. This would convert your string into an array.

There is nothing wrong in doing this. According to me this is the optimal way for doing this.

Once you get the list you can use `filter` method to the array to remove the unwanted element from the list.

Edited:

If it is already stored as array, than you are not required to use split method at all. Already you have the array.
Directly use the splice method to remove the element.
And as you mentioned you need to remove the element by its index, Then just use

```
array.splice(index,1)
```

This index would have your desired index.

Comment: So I need to split out the localStorage array and then access the index? Can you show some code?